# s3 SignedUrl x-amz-security-token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

export function main (event, context, callback) {
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);`

  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.mediaFilesBucket,
    Key: data.name,
    ContentType: data.type,
    ACL: 'public-read',
  };

  const uploadURL = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);

  callback(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ uploadURL: uploadURL }),
  })
}
```

When I test it locally it works fine, but after deployment it x-amz-security-token, and then I get access denied response. How can I get rid of this x-amz-security-token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved a very similar, probably the same issue as you have. I say probably because you dont say what deployment entails for you. I am assuming you are deploying to Lambda but you may not be, this may or may not apply but if you are using temporary credentials this will apply.

I initially used the method you use above but then was using the npm module [aws-signature-v4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-signature-v4) to see if it was different and was getting the same error you are.

You will need the token, it is needed when you have signed a request with temporary credentials. In Lambda's case the credentials are in the runtime, including the session token, which you need to pass, the same is most likely true elsewhere as well but I'm not sure I haven't used ec2 in a few years.

Buried in the docs (and sorry I cannot find the place this is stated) it is pointed out that some services require that the session_token be processed with the other canonical query params. The module I'm using was tacking it on at the end, as the sig v4 instructions seem to imply, so I modified it so the token is canonical and it works.

**We've updated the live version of the aws-signature-v4 module to reflect this change and now it works nicely for signing your s3 requests.**

[Signing is discussed here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).

I would use the module I did as I have a feeling the sdk is doing the wrong thing for some reason.

usage example (this is wrapped in a multiPart upload thus the part number and upload Id):

```
function createBaseUrl( bucketName, uploadId, partNumber, objectKey ) {
  let url = sig4.createPresignedS3URL( objectKey, {
    method: "PUT",
    bucket: bucketName,
    expires: 21600,
    query: `partNumber=${partNumber}&uploadId=${uploadId}`
  });
  return url;
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply! We don't use multipart data though, so I assume that name and type of our file should be defined in the query param. And what is objectKey, is it a name of a file?

Comment: you are welcome, funny we had the same thing at the same time :)

the object key is the file name in S3 terms (which is very confusing). I've not added the content type header yet, though I will before going to production after I get the rest of the workflow completed. That said there is a headers option for the createPresignedS3URL function that the example seems to indicate takes anything you want as an additional header.

Comment: just one more note for you as you may have a different experience than I do. As I'm doing multipart upload I'm specifying the content type when I initiate the multipart upload. So I've got our production version running and it doesn't have the content type header as its not a video, its X number of parts. You should still be able to pass the headers as expected for your use case.

Answer (score 17):

I was having the same issue. Everything was working flawlessly using `serverless-offline` but when I deployed to Lambda I started receiving `AccessDenied` issues on the URL. When comparing the URLs returned between the `serverless-offline` and AWS deployments I noticed the only difference was the inclusion of the `X-Amz-Security-Token` in the URL as a query string parameter. After some digging I discovered the token being assigned was based upon the assumed role the lambda function had. All I had to do was grant the appropriate S3 policies to the role and it worked.

Comment: Hey Sean McMillan. Do you mind sharing which were these missing S3 policies? I am having the same issue with AWS Lambda.

Comment: Not a best practice by far, but S3FullAccess for the role I use with my Lambda solved my issue.

Comment: on serverless.yml I grant s3 access to the lambda function: 
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:*
      Resource: arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*

Comment: If you want to putObject into a bucket, the Lambda that is pre-signing the URLs needs to have permissions to putObject into the bucket. Otherwise, the Lambda creates URLs for actions it's not allowed to perform. Then, you get a 403 error when trying to PUT to that URL, just as the Lambda would if it tried to putObject in the S3 bucket itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I'm creating a signed URL using library Boto3 in python3.7

All though this is not a recommended way to solve, it worked for me.

The request methods should be POST, content-type=['multipart/form-data']

Create a client in like this.

```
# Do not hard code credentials
client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    # Hard coded strings as credentials, not recommended.
    aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY',
    aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
)
```

Return response

```
bucket_name = BUCKET
acl = {'acl': 'public-read-write'}
file_path = str(file_name) //file you want to upload
response = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(bucket_name,
                                                 file_path,
                                                 Fields={"Content-Type": ""},
                                                 Conditions=[acl,
                                                    {"Content-Type": ""},
                                                    ["starts-with", "$success_action_status", ""],
                                                 ],
                                                 ExpiresIn=3600)
```